# ${$} working fine in ksh93 but ${$} not working when I use in cat << EOF

Tags: ksh, variable-substitution, here-document

I'm executing this in the `ksh93` shell.

If I use normally like

```
~# echo ${$}
1295
```

but using `${$}` in a here-document is not working:

```
~#cat <<EOF
~#> ${$}
~#> EOF
syntax error: `$' unexpected
```

But both are working fine with `bash` but not with `ksh93`.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. You may want to report it at https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues

Comment: No one is replied

Comment: How did you report it? I don't see in the list of issues there.

Comment: I have raised new issue in the community .. Issue number 127

Comment: Fixed in: https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/commit/6575903d